# pybrain install in env but No module named 'pybrain'

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, pybrain

I'm new to python and Anaconda

I have python 3.8 in my (base) env, and i need pybrain, so since it's not compatible with my current version of python, i created a new env(first i tried all of it with python 3.5, didn't work, so i tried 2.7, same result):

`conda create --name py27 python=2.7`

then activated it:

`conda activate py27`

and installed pybrain there:

`conda install -c mq pybrain`

I checked that it has been installed successfully with:

`conda list`

`pybrain                   0.3.3                    py27_0    mq`

after launching jupyter notebook from same terminal, with (py27) as the 'header'?? of my command line, it opened successfully, i even checked that currently it's opened in expected environment, by typing in a cell:

`!conda info`

and as i expected,  saw the line

`active environment : py27`

but also, which i guess is importnant:

`python version : 3.8.3.final.0`

though i am confused with ouput of:

`!python --version`

cause it's:

`Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

So when i open my notebook i type

`import pybrain`

and i get:

`No module named 'pybrain'`

Please point me in direction: what i'm doing wrong? Also it is my first virtual env(distinct from the (base) one), so i probably missing some important concepts.

Comment: Have you installed a new jupyter kernel for your new conda environment and selected it in the notebook?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, no i haven't, since i've read in anaconda docs that after creating env with conda, it gets installed automatically, now i checked that the version in ```py27``` is same one as in the ```base``` - 6.0.3 In ipython docs i've read info about manually installing specific version of jupyter kernel. I tried it, but it still shows that the version is 6.0.3. Fortunately i found a solution to use pybrain with python3: i just downloaded it from source. But thanks for information about jupyter kernel, now i know that conda doesn't install jupyter kernel for specified version automatically.

Comment: @Yunnosch, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately i've found a solution to use pybrain with python3 - i just downloaded it from source `!pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip` and it works in python 3.8